# Differentiation operator on smooth function with compact support

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose $f$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support. Let $T_n$ be the operator which sends $f$ to its $n$-th derivative. Is $||T_nf||_\infty$ bounded?

It seems like I should use Stone-Weierstrass, but perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Hint: narrow peak of height $1$.

Comment: I thought about this for a while, but how might I exhibit an actual smooth function?

In fact, how might I exhibit just a smooth function with compact support?

Comment: [Bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Examples) -- then rescale, replacing $x$ by $Nx$.